# How to access the member of an IGrouping?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, grouping

The two lines below return an `IGrouping<string, DataRow>`:

```
var mbVals = GetMBValues_MBvsPU(mbRptDataPkg);
var puVals = GetPUValues_MBvsPU(puRptDataPkg);
```

I'd though that you could access the grouping's data like this `mbVals[StringKey]` but that doesn't look possible. I can do a foreach over the DataRows but it just seems to me one should be able to easily access through a linq expression somehow.

What I'd like to do is compare fields in the datarows from one with fields from datarows of the other through the keys.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`IGrouping<>` is `IEnumerable<>` so you use the `ElementAt()` extension method.

But for the situation you describe, you may be better off using `Zip()` to unify the two groups (if the items are in the same order and match exactly) or using `Join()` if they don't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I tried `ElementAt()` but that's for indexing and foreaching. And Zip is in .net 4 which we're not at yet. Guess I'll have to do it the long way.

Answer (score 0):

An instance that implements `IGrouping<T, U>` has a (one) key of type `T`.  Since you want to compare based on keys (plural), an `IGrouping<string, DataRow>` isn't what you need.

You need an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DataRow>>` or an `ILookup<string, DataRow>`.  Something that has many keys.

```
ILookup<string, DataRow> source1 = GetSource1();
ILookup<string, DataRow> source2 = GetSource2();

var BothKeyed = 
(
 from key in source1.Select(g => g.Key).Union(source2.Select(g => g.Key))
 select new
 {
   Key = key,
   In1 = source1[key],//note, In1 may be empty.
   In2 = source2[key] //note, In2 may be empty.
 }
).ToLookup(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I should have said, the Grouping is already an `IQueryable<IGrouping<string, DataRow>>` that's what `GroupBy` Returns.